# Expose an installed SDK package in the start menu

Tags: installation, windows-11, installer, sdk

I am maintaining a software package that installs as a set of files in folders plus a series of executables. It is a complete SDK. I have developed an installer using Visual Studio and had been quite happy with it for years.

Anyway, much to my despair, when installing under Windows 11, the package components have become virtually invisible and unreachable.

- there is nothing telling you that new stuff was installed,
- there is no folder-like grouping showing you the available executables nor the data files,
- if you type the product name in the start menu, at best you get irrelevant entries.

This is to the point that I myself, even knowing the names of the utility programs, am often unable to find and launch them.

As far as the promotion of the product (freely downloadable) is concerned, this is a total disaster. Also in terms of ergonomic for the knowledgeable users.

How is this handled in the Windows 11-ish way ?